# What is "AddType" in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What is the difference those?

> AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
>
> AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
>
> AddType x-httpd-php .php

?

The page loading speed significantly decreases when I have `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php` .
Why would that be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It tells apache what mime-type to return when encountering that extension.
See the docs here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype

Mime-types are used for several things in Apache.

1. to tell the browser how to treat the file
2. to tell apache which handler to use

With `AddHandler` you can bind a handler (like PHP) to a specific mime-type. So using a different mime-type for PHP could result in a different parser being used.

Comment: `AddHandler` is used to bind a server side handler to a **file extension**, not a mime-type. See the syntax in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler

Answer (score 3):

AddType associates a mime type with a given extension.

Answer (score 1):

It's mostly explained by the *Network Working Group* explanations:

> The Multipurpose Internet Message Extensions (MIME) define a facility an object can contain a reference or pointer to some form of rather than the actual data itself. (...)

In other words: You're telling *Apache* to *`AddType`*/associate a specific *MIME* type with a specific file extension. Then *Apache* ships files that have a specific extension with exactly this associated `header`.